# Не полностью переведен диалог отката правки

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, откат-правок

> [image: All changes made after this revision will be rolled back.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавил перевод:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15740

И ещё один смежный:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15743

Будет на сайте в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2021.1.18.38333